# Check for null cells in HTML Table

Tags: jquery, html

So I have this div on my page:

```
<div id="valueTableBTS"></div>
```

This div gets filled with an html table dynamically. What I want to be able to do in JQuery is to check if this table has any empty cells, so I know if I need to keep calling my other method to fill it with any newly grabbed values.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get you right, this should do it:

```
if( $('#valueTableBTS tbody').find('td:empty').length ) {
    // at least one <td> is empty
}
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/p53Y8/

---

The [`:empty`<sup>help</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/) selector will find nodes which have no children (including text nodes).

Comment: Works fine for me, you just have to be careful that the cells have no whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($("#valueTableBTS").children(".cellClass").length == 0) {
    //blah
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After the table is inserted, you could iterate through the TDs:

```
$('.yourTable td').each(function(){

    if ($(this).text=""){
        //it's blank
    }
  })
```